# Can we choose norms such that $\mathbb R^m\otimes\mathbb R^n\cong\mathbb R^{mn}$ is an isometry?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, tensor-products

$\mathbb R^m\otimes\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^{mn}$ are (algebraically) isomorphic. Is there a norm on $\mathbb R^{mn}$ such that this isomorphism is an isometry when $\mathbb R^m\otimes\mathbb R^n$ is equipped with the injective or projective tensor norm?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because these are finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, the (Hilbert-Schmidt) norm on the tensor product is the standard one on $\mathbb R^{mn}$. Checking on a basis, or checking more abstractly, both succeed.

EDIT (in response to query from the original poster): what I would call the Hilbert-Schmidt norm on the *algebraic* tensor product of two Hilbert spaces $V,W$ is completely specified by
$$
\langle v\otimes w,\;v'\otimes w'\rangle \;=\; \langle v,v'\rangle_V\cdot \langle w,w'\rangle_W
$$
(This extends bilinearly to completely define the thing...)

Comment: How is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm defined for a tensor?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: please reread **your** question carefully and have a look at my answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for editing. So, with "standard one" you mean the Frobenius norm on $\mathbb R^{mn}$, right?

Comment: Yes, what I call the Hilbert-Schmidt norm (for some Hilbert-space operator reasons) is also called the Frobenius norm, I believe.

Comment: @paulgarrett Afaik, that's correct. I think I haven't done a good job in writing my question; what I really want to know is if there is one of the "common" matrix norms such that the $\mathbb R^m\otimes\mathbb R^n\cong\mathbb R^{mn}$ holds isometrically when $\mathbb R^m\otimes\mathbb R^n$ is equipped with the injective norm.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $A$ is isomorphic to $B$ as a vector space via some linear transformation $f: A \to B$ and if $B$ is equipped with a norm, there is a simple, obvious and unique way of equipping $A$ with a norm that makes $f$ an isometry.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should had state the question differently: If the tensor product is equipped with the injective norm, is that isomorphism an isometry when $\mathbb R^{mn}$ is equipped with one of the "common" norms (p-norm, Frobenius norm, etc.).